# How to know if primary & replica shard in elasticsearch land up on same data node ?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to alert / detect in elasticsearch when the primary shard and replica shard land up on the same data node ? May be via datadog or any other way ?

Looking for an automatic way not manual way like monitoring through head plugin etc.

Comment: it is not possible for a replica shard to land on the same node as its primary shard (by design).

Comment: Replica is copy of your main shard, it doesn't make sense to store on same machine, your cluster will be yellow if replica can't be allocated.

Comment: Correct it doesn't make sense to have primary & replica on same node. Was just wondering "if" there's any remote chance of them being allotted on the same node.